# Replace an existing javascript element for another

Tags: javascript

**What I can do:**
I have an array of objects, when the user clicks on a name, an image will appear, when the user clicks in that image a count of the clicks will show.

**What I can't do:**
When the user clicks on another name, the existing image and the numbers of clicks should be replaced for the recently clicked one. Can you help me to achieve this?

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0]= {name: "Mel", img : "img/ml.jpg", clicks : 0};
myArray[1]= {name: "Ang", img : "img/ma.jpg", clicks : 0};
myArray[2]= {name: "Cam", img : "img/mk.jpg", clicks : 0};
myArray[3]= {name: "Val", img : "img/vs.jpg", clicks : 0};
myArray[4]= {name: "Gab", img : "img/ga.jpg", clicks : 0};

let elemName=[];
let elemImg=[];
let elemClick=[];

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {      //create elements
  elemName[i] = document.createElement("h2");
  elemName[i].textContent = myArray[i].name;
  elemImg[i] = document.createElement("img");
  elemImg[i].src = myArray[i].img;
  elemClick[i] = document.createElement("h3");
  elemClick[i].textContent = myArray[i].clicks;

elemImg[i].onclick=function(){                  //count clicks
  myArray[i].clicks++;
  elemClick[i].textContent = myArray[i].clicks;
};

document.body.appendChild(elemName[i]); //Show names

 elemName[i].onclick=function(){        //When a name is clicked, display image and number of clicks, replacing the existing one

  //????????????????

  document.body.appendChild(elemImg[i]); 
  document.body.appendChild(elemClick[i]);
};
```

Comment: I think you would be better off using replaceChild()

Answer (score 0):

- Create all images with `display: none` to start
- When a name is clicked on, use display: none on all images, and then display: block; or display: inline; on the image you want to display
- Create a `DIV` and use `CSS zScore : 1` to display on top of everything. Put your count in this `DIV`. You will also probably want to use `CSS position: relative` or `position:absolute` to place the `DIV` in the right place

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I'm trying to do this only with JS